# Fixed point of a map

Tags: general-topology

If g is a continuous map from U onto V in the complex plane, where U and V are homeomorphic to disks and U a proper subset of V. Must there be a fixed point? And if g is conformal, is this point unique?

Thanks.

Sorry, I meant g is from U onto V.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To attract answers to your question, please add some context and background information. For example, where did you encounter this problem (e.g. a book, class, real-life)? Please also show your attempt; seeing your work helps us help you. If this is homework, please read [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/23353).

Answer (score 2):

No, let $V$ be the disk of radius $60$ and centered at the origin, let $U$ be the disk of radius $1$ and centered at $-2$, and let $g(x) = x+3$.

Comment: but g is not onto

Comment: Right, the question was edited after I wrote the above answer.